# Transact-SQL -- reference another unit for common definitions?

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

In Transact-SQL for Azure SQL Database, is there any facility in stored procedures or user-defined functions to include or reference another unit to get common definitions?  I frequently cut and paste variables used as constant definitions between procedures and am looking for a better way.  I am aware of user-defined table types.

Comment: Your question doesn't include enough useful detail for us to help you. Check out [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the importance of a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). After that, [start here](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to edit your question as needed.

Comment: @EricBrandt He's asking for something similar to includes (C/C++ style) or import style functionality, to have one place to define constants, variables, types and so on.

Comment: Relevant link on dba.stackexchange: [Is there a concept of an “include file” in SQL Server?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/13891/65699). In any case: no. T-SQL by itself has no such concept.

Comment: @TT., thanks for the clarification. I wasn't drawing the analogy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comment by TT:  No. T-SQL by itself has no such concept.